# Path for a Views 3 page

Tags: views

Is it possible to set a Views 3 path for a page to *%/%* **instead of**, for example, *factsheets/%/%* ?

The preview works, but the actual view doesn't.  I'm thinking it shouldn't, but can't find anything to confirm one way or another.

Answer (score 1):

I do not believe that a path such as %/% in views will work.  Have you tried it?

The path factsheet/%/%  is not intercepting other content, it is the path to the view page.  That means that views responds to any page with a factsheets followed by other path segments.  The reason for defining the view pages with % is to create a wildcard variable to be used in contextual filters (3rd column of the main view form).  These filters supplement the basic  filters defined in the first column.  Having two % filters means that you can use two contextual filters.  The top contextual filter takes the first % and the second takes the next % in the path.

The Views preview works because you are only testing the contextual filters.  The path is not being run through Drupal to determine content.

Comment: For future questions, try expanding upon what you are trying to do and what you have tried.  It will help responders give better targeted answers.  If you like their answers, check the up arrow to recognize their effort.  IF you accept the answer as the correct one. click the check mark.

Comment: Oh, I understand how Views works. I'm just wondering about the specific case above. It reads right, but  think extra emphasis is needed.  Have added this to the original question now.